# jQuery fullcalendar do not get events when key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I have jQuery fullcalendar with simple search.

```
        search.keyup(function( event ) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if ( keycode !== 13 ) {
                throw ('Script Exit');
            }
            else{
                events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                searchValue(events);
            }
        });
```

When I pressed any key in search input I see that fullcalendar get source from my PHP script. How can I turn off this?

Comment: do you know what `refetchEvents` is for?

Answer (score 1):

this is what I would do:

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'month',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev, next'
        }
        // other options...
    });

        function getCurrEventsArr(calendar) {
            var events_arr = new Array();
            calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                event = "";//code to make any changes to event
                events_arr.push(event);
            });
            return events_arr;
        }

       search.keyup(function() {
          var events =  getCurrEventsArr(calendar);
          console.log(events);
       });
```